# Error when archive project: ld: can't open output file for writing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive, app-distribution

When I run my application on a device, it works perfect, but when I am trying to Archive it to upload to iTunes Connect, i get this error:

Error 1:

> ld: can't open output file for writing:
>   /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Drikkespillet-bmengfxihzksonhdoqpbllpzpagg/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Drikkespillet/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Drikkespillet.build/Release-iphoneos/Drikkespillet.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Drikkespillet,
>   errno=21 for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Error 2:

> ld: can't open output file for writing:
>   /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Drikkespillet-bmengfxihzksonhdoqpbllpzpagg/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Drikkespillet/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Drikkespillet.build/Release-iphoneos/Drikkespillet.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Drikkespillet,
>   errno=21 for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried to remove both of the "Framework Search Paths" and "Library Search Paths". But it still does not work to Archive the project. Any suggestions here?

Comment: I get a similar error; I can build to devices, but can't Archive;

`error: unable to open '[paths/paths]/myapp.app.dSYM': No such file or directory.`

They're a little similar in that Xcode can't seem to write required output.

Comment: I am also getting this same issue when i upgraded to latest xcode version..

Comment: Has anyone got a solution to this problem yet?

Answer (score 2):

In Project file go to build setting -->**Architectures section** --> **valid Architectures** -- >Delete **arm64**.